# yii2 formatter прибавляет лишний год

Tags: php, yii2, дата

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При выводе даты с помощью класса **Formatter->asDate()**, к результату прибавляется год. Если вывести через **date()** - все ок. Происходит это в том случае если формат *'dd.MM.Y'* (если *'dd.MM.y'* - все ок). И в моем примере такой баг выскакивает есть при значении *"2019-12-30T00:00:00+02:00"* (30 декабря). В результате получаю: 30.12.2020. Баг так же если 31 декабря.
Если вместо него к примеру подставить не 30 декабря, а 30 ноября, то все будет корректно. Дебагом дошел до класса IntlDateFormatter. Дальше - не понятно. Я то могу подстроить другое решение, но интересно почему выстреливает именно этот кейс.
Помогите разобраться в чем может быть причина.

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0):

В общем нашел описание:
https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details

Оказывается между Y и y есть разница в плане недель насколько я понял.

Comment: Я всегда думал это 4 и 2 значный формат.

Comment: Ну если к примеру просто юзать date(), то для него будет как говорите вы:
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

А если взять к примеру класс IntlDateFormatter, то он берет их по ссылке выше. И работает получается немножко иначе

Comment: мы в последнее время карбоном пользуемся, там много полезных методов есть, может нет такого бага https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Та как выяснилось - это не баг. Я просто до этого не знал, что есть разница и думал что баг. А выходит это разные вещи, просто нужно правильно их использовать. Но все равно спасибо за ответы)